# Is it bad practice to set component style using useRef and style.setProperty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, animation, tailwind-css

In my React / Tailwind app, I have a component, ErrorMessage, which I use to display validation errors under inputs in user forms. I didn't like the way that when a user submits a form and there's a validation error, the error immediately appears under the form, shifting the rest of the form downwards.

To solve this, I've implemented the ErrorMessage component like so:

```js
function ErrorMessage({ error }: { error: string | null }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pRef.current) {
      if (error === null) pRef.current.style.setProperty('height', '0px');
      else {
        pRef.current.style.setProperty('height', '20px');
      }
    }
  }, [error]);
  const pRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);

  return (
    <p
      ref={pRef}
      className='ml-1 overflow-hidden text-xs font-medium italic text-red-500  transition-all duration-200'
    >
      {error}
    </p>
  );
}
```

The idea is that I set overflow:hidden on the <p> tag, give it a reference and then use that reference to animate a change in height whenever the error message changes (i.e. goes from there being an error to not being an error and vice versa).

Is it bad practice to set styling on the tag using a reference to it in the way that I am? I know that typically in React you should use state to trigger changes but I couldn't find a way to do so.

Similarly, is there a better way of implementing what I'm trying to achieve (ideally without a library) which is preventing my form from jankily growing/shrinking when an input has an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a bad practice.

Manually adding/removing styles is verbose and error prone. You want React to render itself according to the current state or props passed in. Abiding by this rule actually makes things *much* simpler.

Far as I can tell, this does the *exact* same thing:

```
function ErrorMessage({ error }: { error: string | null }) {
  return (
    <p
      className='ml-1 overflow-hidden text-xs font-medium italic text-red-500  transition-all duration-200'
      style={{ height: error ? '20px': '0px' }}
    >
      {error}
    </p>
  );
}
```

Well, nearly the same thing. No `useEffect` means the that the style is set when the component renders, and not in an effect that runs afterward.

---

In general, you want to avoid imperative code (when this happens, do this), and instead write declarative code (given this state, here's how it should look).

Declarative code is what React was designed around, and is much harder to get wrong.

---

Pretty much the only reason to use an approach like this is when you need this to be fast, like you are animating something at 60 frames per second and triggering the react state lifecycle would be too slow.

But if all you want to do is toggle visibility of an error, then there's no reason to make things more complicated for yourself.